# How to add custom repository in pom while I'm using nexus for proxing?

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I'm trying to use nexus to proxy central repository which is quite slow.
So. I've configured maven according tutorial.

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
     </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Everything is working fine and fast. But I faced with problem when I've tried to use custom repository specified in pom.xml (this repo is needed only for concrete project)

So. I'm talking about:

```
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>dtrott</id>
    <url>http://maven.davidtrott.com/repository</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

from: https://github.com/dtrott/maven-protoc-plugin#readme

error message:

```
Error resolving version for plugin 'com.google.protobuf.tools:maven-protoc-plugin' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\valden\.m2\repository), nexus (http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
```

In maven settings.xml I've changed next line:

```
<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
```

to

```
<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
```

and it is working now...

Comment: Big thanks! I've spent fifteen minutes trying to figure this out until I found your question/answer.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to add the custom repository to your `Nexus` as a proxied repository (type `proxy`). Then you don't have to put anything extra in your `pom`.

Comment: I've tried to do this... But unfortunately nexus did not wanted to download index from this `dtrott` repository...

Comment: S3 repository... have a look at those: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-1121 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625553/how-can-i-get-nexus-to-proxy-springsource-maven-repository-on-s3

Comment: Even if that proxy repository does not have an index it will still work for accessing any artifacts from it. It will just not show them in the search. But you can e.g. browse the remote repo to find what is there..